# Problem: Retrieving records from kinesis data streams taking forever because of empty shard iterators. How do I avoid this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

Here's my loop to retrieve records from kinesis data stream:

```
public async Task PrintAllShards()
   {
        var shardIds = await GetShardIds();
        foreach (var shardId in shardIds)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting: " + shardId);
            int count = 0;
            var shardIterator = await GetShardIterator(shardId, _shardIteratorType);
            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(shardIterator) && count < 400)
            {
                count++;
                //Console.WriteLine("ShardId: " + shardId + " Iterator Count: "+ count+ " sharditerator: " + shardIterator);
                var getRecordsResponse = await _kinesisClient.GetRecordsAsync(new GetRecordsRequest
                {
                    ShardIterator = shardIterator
                });
                if (getRecordsResponse.Records.Count > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("At count = "+count +" Found " + getRecordsResponse.Records.Count);
                }
                foreach (var record in getRecordsResponse.Records)
                {
                    
                    Console.WriteLine("*********" + record.SequenceNumber);
                }
                shardIterator = getRecordsResponse.NextShardIterator;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("ShardId: " + shardId + " Iterator Count: " + count);
        }
    }
```

I have 4 shards and in each shard exactly two shard iterators contain records.  I don't understand why there are "empty" iterators.  Is there some way to eliminate them or better avoid creating them in the first place?  Is there some better way to retrieve records that avoids this?